# How to find the concurrent.future input arguments for a Dask distributed function call

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm using Dask to distribute work to a cluster. I'm creating a cluster and calling `.submit()` to submit a function to the scheduler. It returns a Futures object. I'm trying to figure out how to obtain the input arguments to that future object once it's been completed.

For example:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask_yarn import YarnCluster

def somefunc(a,b,c ..., n ):
    # do something
    return


cluster = YarnCluster.from_specification(spec)
client = Client(cluster)

future = client.submit(somefunc, arg1, arg2, ..., argn)

# ^^^ how do I obtain the input arguments for this future object?
# `future.args` doesn't work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Futures don't hold onto their inputs.  You can do this yourself though.

```
futures = {}
future = client.submit(func, *args)

futures[future] = args
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with `client.map()`?

Answer (score 1):

A future only knows the key by which it is uniquely known on the scheduler. At the time of submission, if it has dependencies, these are transiently found and sent to the scheduler but no copy if kept locally.

The pattern you are after sounds more like `delayed`, which keeps hold of its graph, and indeed `client.compute(delayed_thing)` returns a future.

```
d = delayed(somefunc)(a, b, c)
future = client.compute(d)
dict(d.dask)  # graph of things needed by d
```

You could communicate directly with the scheduler to find the dependencies of some key, which will in general also be keys, and so reverse-engineer the graph, but that does not sound like a great path, so I won't try to describe it here.